# Creating an Array of ErrorProvider in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to show an error whenever one of the fields is not empty...
doing it the old way one field at a time is time and effort consuming... so is there a way to create an array of `ErrorProvider` to handle this matter?

[The GUI of the Add Item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRhyN.png)

and here is the code i have till now...

```
try
        {
            if (TxtModule.Text != String.Empty && CmbParts.Text != String.Empty && TxtBrand.Text != String.Empty && TxtHeadMat.Text != String.Empty && TxtIPP.Text != String.Empty && TxtRate.Text != String.Empty && TxtManu.Text != String.Empty && TxtPrice.Text != String.Empty && TxtQuan.Text != String.Empty && TxtSN.Text != String.Empty && TxtToolsize.Text != String.Empty)
            {


                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                    CommandText = "Insert Into Items ([PartName], [SerialNum], [ModNum], [ToolSize], [Manufact], [Brand], [Price], [Quant], [ItemsPerPack], [HeadMaterial], [Describe]) VALUES(@PatN,@SerialNum,@ModNum, @ToolSize,@Manu,@Brnd,@Prce,@Qty, @IPP,@HeadMat,@Describe)"
                };
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatN", CmbParts.SelectedItem.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNum", TxtSN.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModNum", TxtModule.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ToolSize", TxtToolsize.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manu", TxtManu.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Brnd", TxtBrand.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prce", TxtPrice.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", TxtQuan.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IPP", TxtIPP.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HeadMat", TxtHeadMat.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Describe", TxtDescription.Text);
                cmd.Connection = GetConnection();
                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Inserted", "Success");
                    this.Close();
                    
                }
            }

            else
            {
                ErrorProvider CmbdError = new ErrorProvider();
                CmbdError.SetError(CmbParts, "What item to add");
                CmbParts.Focus();
                ErrorProvider SNError = new ErrorProvider();
                SNError.SetError(TxtSN, "Define Serial Number");
                TxtSN.Focus();
                ErrorProvider ModuleError = new ErrorProvider();
                ModuleError.SetError(TxtModule, "Define Module Number");
                TxtModule.Focus();
                ErrorProvider ToolSizeError = new ErrorProvider();
                ToolSizeError.SetError(TxtToolsize, "Set Tool Size");
                TxtToolsize.Focus();
                ErrorProvider ManufactorError = new ErrorProvider();
                ManufactorError.SetError(TxtManu, "Defind Manufacturer");
                TxtManu.Focus();
                ErrorProvider BrandError = new ErrorProvider();
                BrandError.SetError(TxtBrand, "Define Brand");
                TxtBrand.Focus();//list goes on 
            }
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: A single `ErrorProvider` can handle multiple errors. You don't need one for each control. Also, `ErrorProvider` implements `IDisposable` and should be disposed. In other words, it should be declared as a class member variable, and is disposed in the parent control's `Dispose(bool disposing)` method.

Comment: Also, you should be using the `Validating` event. For example, `TxtSN.Validating += (o, e) => { if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TxtSN.Text)) { e.Cancel = true; errorProvider.SetError(TxtSN, "Serial Number is required."); } };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you just need a single `ErrorProvider` component to report the errors. The `ErrorProvider` implements the [IExtenderProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.iextenderprovider?view=net-5.0) interface to extend the controls in the container and provide additional properties, namely the `Error`,
`IconAlignment`, and `IconPadding` provider properties. So, you just need to set/get their values through the dedicated setter/getter methods.

- [ErrorProvider.GetError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.geterror?view=net-5.0) and [ErrorProvider.SetError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seterror?view=net-5.0)
- [ErrorProvider.GetIconAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.geticonalignment?view=net-5.0) and [ErrorProvider.SetIconAlignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seticonalignment?view=net-5.0)
- [ErrorProvider.GetIconPadding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.geticonpadding?view=net-5.0) and [ErrorProvider.SetIconPadding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider.seticonpadding?view=net-5.0)

---

In your case, create a method to get the controls:

```cs
private IEnumerable<Control> GetAllControls(Control parent, bool recursively = false)
{
    // You will be needing this if the controls are hosted by different containers.
    if (recursively)
    {
        var cs = parent.Controls.OfType<Control>();
        return cs.SelectMany(c => GetAllControls(c)).Concat(cs);
    }
    else
        return parent.Controls.OfType<Control>();
}
```

And validate the entries as follows:

```cs
private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    errorProvider1.Clear();

    var cs = GetAllControls(this, true);

    foreach (var c in cs)
    {
        if (c is TextBox && c.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
            errorProvider1.SetError(c, "Error message...");
        else if (c is ComboBox cb && cb.SelectedIndex == -1)
            errorProvider1.SetError(c, "Error Message...");
        // else for more types...
    }

    var first = cs.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorProvider1.GetError(x)));

    if (first != null)
    {
        first.Focus();
        return;
    }

    // else you are good to go...
}
```

If you create the `ErrorProvider` in code rather that dropping an instance into the designer, then you should also dispose of it.

```cs
private void someForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    errorProviderCreatedByCode.Dispose();
}
```

---

I see in your code snippet that you need to set different `Error` messages. in this case you need to link the controls with their messages in some way.

**Solution 1: Control.Tag**

Set the `Tag` property at design time for each control to store the `Error` values.

Validation code. Revisit 1.

```cs
private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    errorProvider1.Clear();

    var cs = GetAllControls(this, true);
    string err;

    foreach (var c in cs)
    {
        err = c.Tag as string;

        if (c is TextBox && c.Text.Trim().Length == 0 && err != null)
            errorProvider1.SetError(c, err);
        else if (c is ComboBox cb && cb.SelectedIndex == -1 && err != null)
            errorProvider1.SetError(c, err);
        // else for more types...
    }

    var first = cs.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorProvider1.GetError(x)));

    if (first != null)
    {
        first.Focus();
        return;
    }

    // Good to go...            
}
```

**Solution 2: Dictionary<Control, string>**

At runtime, create a key-value pair collection for the controls and their messages.

```cs
private readonly Dictionary<Control, string> dict;

private void someForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dict = new Dictionary<Control, string>()
    {
        { CmbParts, "What item to add" },
        { TxtSN, "Define Serial Number" },
        { TxtModule, "Define Module Number" },
        // add more...
    };
}
```

Validation code. Revisit 2.

```cs
private void someButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    errorProvider1.Clear();

    var cs = GetAllControls(this, true);
    string err;

    foreach (var c in cs)
    {
        if (c is TextBox && c.Text.Trim().Length == 0 && dict.TryGetValue(c, out err))
            errorProvider1.SetError(c, err);
        else if (c is ComboBox cb && cb.SelectedIndex == -1 && dict.TryGetValue(c, out err))
            errorProvider1.SetError(c, err);
        // else for more types...
    }

    var first = cs.FirstOrDefault(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorProvider1.GetError(x)));

    if (first != null)
    {
        first.Focus();
        return;
    }

    // Good to go...
}
```

Comment: lovely, It worked but what about the datTimePicker1? how can i show an error message if the date was Date..Today???

Comment: Thank you. Same way.. `else if (c is DateTimePicker dtp && dtp.Value.Date == DateTime.Today.Date && err != null)`. But are you sure about `Today`? What if the today's date is a valid entry? Perhaps better to enable the DateTimePicker.ShowCheckBox property and set the error in the validation routine if the DateTimePicker.Checked property is false. i.e. `else if (c is DateTimePicker dtp && !dtp.Checked && err != null) errorProvider1.SetError(c, err);`.