# Collect textboxes in a collection and validate

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to collect up a number of text boxes and test against what is entered. I know this has been answered several times but most cases want to collect all the controls in a panel or form, I want to choose each text box.

I'm trying this, based on another stack overflow answer [Loop through textboxes in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30604633/loop-through-textboxes-in-vb-net) but it not working for me. Null reference exception, which presumably I've not instantiated my object but I have I not, with the new keyword....
In summary why does this not work?

```
Dim boxes As New List(Of TextBox)() From {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5}

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TestTextBox()
End Sub

Private Sub TestTextBox()

For Each tb As TextBox In boxes
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(tb.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Text box is empty")
    ElseIf tb.Text.Length > 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Characters limited to 10")
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to test the length of the input when you can set the `MaxLength` of the `TextBox`?

Comment: That's not really the way to do validation in WinForms. You should handle the `Validating` event of each control and perform the validation there, setting `e.Cancel` to `True` if it fails. The user will then not be able to navigate away from the control until they enter valid data. You can then call `ValidateChildren` on the `Click` of the `Button` to validate all controls, including those that that never received focus. If that returns `True` then every control passed validation.

Comment: thanks for the replies, I'll check the validation out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `null` list objects in the loop because you create a class collection and initialize it to add controls that haven't been created nor initialized yet. The `boxes` is created before the Form's constructor calls the `InitializeComponent();` to create and initialize the hosted controls including the text boxes in question. So you need to wait for the controls to be created to access them.

Declare a `List<TextBox>`:

```vb
Public Class YourForm
    Private ReadOnly boxes As List(Of TextBox)
```

Then in the constructor, instantiate it and pass the elements:

```vb
    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        boxes = New List(Of TextBox) From {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5}
    End Sub
End Class
```

Side note, you can set the `MaxLength` property of the text boxes to be `10` and omit this `ElseIf tb.Text.Length > 10 Then...`

Comment: thanks , its working now. As per the other comments it seem validation is the way to go, but I've accepted your answer.

Comment: @Nick You are welcome. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65966553/14171304) another approach to validate controls of different types. If you just need to validate TextBox controls, then consider John's suggestion.